# calling a function before onclick script

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, handler

```
<a href="#" onclick="foo()">click me </a>
```

Hello, I need to called a function before calling the onclick script when the  is clicked.

I tried:

```
    var script = $("a").attr("onclick");
    $("a").attr("onclick", "");

    $("a").click(function(event) {
       // call bar() first, then foo();
       bar();
       // script is a string on Chrome
       // foo() may use this, so can not globalEval.
    });
```

how to call the script? Can I get the onclick as jQuery function? so that:

```
 onclickFunction.call(this);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you must follow this way try this:

**JS:**

```
(function() {
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    var foo = a.onclick;

    function bar() { console.log('bar'); } 

    a.onclick = function() {
        bar(); 
        foo();
    };
})();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a36myr6x/)

Comment: Thanks. How to do this using jQuery?  $("a").onclick is not defined. $("a").attr("onclick") returns a string, not a function.

Comment: I tried this. It works if the foo() does not access this.xxxx.

Comment: <script>
    function foo(id) {
        console.log('foo ' + id);
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="foo(this.id)">click me </a>. The id is not defined.

Comment: In this case 'this' is reference to window object, so you trying access to window.id.

Comment: this is reference to the <a>. If I click <a> without the a.onclick overrides, it works. In jQuery, it can call a function passing a parameter as this,  for example, aFuntion.call(jQueryObjectAsThis)

Answer (score 1):

You can add "mouse up" or "mouse down" event to the element, this event will call before the "click" event call. Here is the demo.

```js
void function(){
  $("div").mousedown(function(){
  console.log("mouse down event") 
  })
  $("div").mouseup(function(){
  console.log("mouse up event") 
  })
  $("div").click(function(){
  console.log("click event") 
  })
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you wrap them inside another function like this? :

```
<a href="#" onclick="handler();">click me </a>

var handler = function() {
   foo(); // 1. calling foo first
   bar(); // 2. calling bar second
};
```